# Is there a utility to create a Gantt chart of process children?

Tags: process

I would like to call a particular process, and monitor all the child processes spawned by it (and their children, recursively).  I would want to monitor all the children like this for the entire lifetime of the process.

After the process terminates I would like to visualize this information as a Gantt chart, similar in presentation to how the program "bootchart" does its visualization, or how in many modern browsers developer tools "Network" tab looks, as another example.

Are there existing tools I can use for such a task?